# Real Analysis Use of Darboux's Theorem Help

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The question I'm trying to answer is:

Let $I$ be an interval and let $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $I$. Show that if the derivative $f'$ is never 0 on $I$, then either $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ or $f'(x)<0$ for all $x$.

I know I can apply Darboux's Theorem to solve the question.

My Attempt: Let $I=[a,b]$. If $k$ is a number s.t. $f'(a)<k<f'(b)$, then there exists a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ s.t. $f'(c)=k$. Because $f'\neq0$, $0<f'(a)<k<f'(b)$.

I'm really stuck.. Could somebody help me out here? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much simpler than that: If you had a point where $f'(x)$ were negative and another point with $f'(y)$ positive, then there is a point between $x$ and $y$ for which $f'$ is zero (by Darboux's theorem). This contradicts the assumption.

Comment: Very clever! Why couldn't I think like that? Thanks a lot!