# Bartle, Introduction to Real Analysis (2011 4 ed), Ex 14, Section 6.2, p 179.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $I$ be an interval and let $I : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $I$. Show that if the derivative $f'$ is never $0$ on $I$, then either $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$ or $f' (x) < 0$ for all $x \in I$.

I was thinking to proceed by Darboux's theorem. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, it should follow from Darboux in one line.

Comment: If $f'$ is continuous you may use the Bolzano.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_%28analysis%29) makes it unnecessary.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Indeed it is so. I just mentioned it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real Analysis Use of Darboux's Theorem Help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835855/real-analysis-use-of-darbouxs-theorem-help)

Comment: Every derivative satisfies the intermediate value property. Hence the result follows immediately. For a proof of the first result, check the section on the continuity of derivatives in, say, Baby Rudin.